# Streams vs monads

Tags: stream, scheme, monads, categories, lazy-evaluation

Does exist any difference between streams (lazy lists) and monads?
From conceptual and mathematical points of view, not from technical implementation.

Or else, does exist biunique, one-to-one correspondence between?

More exactly, as streams it means "even streams" from the [SRFI-41](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-41/srfi-41.html) of the Scheme language.

Is it another category than monads? If so, what category is it?

May "even streams" guarantee the control of side effects, like monads?

Comment: As far as I understand, Scheme's streams are lazy values whereas Monads are custom chaining of computations.

Comment: Streams are exactly lazy lists. How can "lazy values" be presented without monads or again lazy lists or something like? Don't confuse "lazy values" with immutable functional variables. Well, and does "custom chaining of computations" have one-to-one correspondence with "even streams"?

Comment: Well. Compare definitions of both "even streams" and monads. And also their axioms. As I know, each stream can be expressed via a monad. Is it true what each monadic "value" or "computation" can be expressed via an "even stream"? Is there any limitation?

Comment: Lazy values are just deferred computations, what Scheme calls promises. Monads are computations that are related to each other in some way (for example, they need to be sequential). These two are different concepts, as far I see.

Comment: @Salil But what is "deferred computation" (promise)? In SICP it is said what "delay" is just "syntactic sugar" for lambda! And "force" is just usual call! Though they may be implemented differently, but they are expressed this way. Just usual values. And though monads are different concept from "lazy values", streams are different either. Because they are "lazy lists". And because for now we still have no definition what are "lazy values". A delay is a delay, a promise is a promise - these are usual values, not lazy. They are maybe building elements for laziness, but not lazy themselves. IMHO.

Answer (score 6):

As Salil already said, the two are different concepts:

A **stream** is a (potentially infinite) list of values, typically, but not necessarily, computed in lazy fashion, i.e., only storing some way of computing the values when requested. There's a lot of examples around that do not involve monads in any way:

```
(define integers (cons-stream 1 (stream-map (lambda (x) (+ x 1)) integers))
```

It is quite useful to also consider finite, precomputed, lists as streams, since you can use them anywhere a (potentially or necessarily) finite lazy stream could be used.

So, a stream is something that has an operation `next: streamType -> (valueType streamType)` to get the next value and the remaining stream.

**Monads,** on the other hand, are less of a data structure and more a way of writing source code by combining individual commands.

Probably the simplest useful example is the “Maybe monad” – I'm not sure what it would look like in Scheme, sorry, but the idea is: Given a list of computations `(f g h)` and an input `x`, carry out the computations in order, almost as if given `(f (g (h x)))`, but let each function fail gracefully: If `g` returns `nil`, do not invoke `(f nil)`, but instead, return `nil` immediately.

You can, of course, combine the two in various useful ways and compute your stream values with monads or encapsulate the use of streams like I/O streams that are not exactly following the expectations of functional programming in a monad (to avoid code storing a reference to some previous state of the stream), but they serve completely different purposes. Think about the abstraction layer (close the cover, don't look at the innards): A monad, applied to functions, gives you a function. A stream, on the other hand, is not some higher function, but a list of values.

Obviously, the function defined by (or returned from, depending on your point of view) the monad can be an implementation of a stream, and also, the values extracted from a stream can be monads. But as you can see above, there are monads implementing things completely different from streams. Whether there are streams not implemented as monads probably depends on just what exactly you use the term for. I must confess I'm not sure at the moment if infinite streams properly qualify as monads; finite lists obviously do.

Comment: Your answer is much more usefull. And objections to previous answer were not against any difference. Just it was the matter of the question to find the difference. But objections to previous answer were against the equation of "lazy values" with Scheme's promises. And against something else, but not against any difference at all.

Comment: Well, just in the text of the question was the suggestion not to look "under the cover". So, what is the diff between a "data structure" and a "way of" doing something ("writing code")? From the view point of abstraction from the time and states. To say that something is more or less a "data structure". And are "lazy lists" structures or just a "way"? Because the statement that "streams are exactly lazy lists" was only a objection to "lazy values". From this it does not follow that stream are exactly "data structures".

Comment: Your reasonings about a "higher function" are more stronger IMHO. Though it still needs a proof that there is not any way to use "even streams" as higher functions. So it would be proved that streams are more restrictive than modads. But to say that they are *completely* different, don't forget that streams can be expressed via monads. So streams are just a subcategory of monads. But is this subcategory a strict "sub"? Or is it only a partial intersection? IMHO the question is open.

Comment: To avoid discussions in the comments, let me edit my answer a little.

Comment: Of course, please do any editions that you want. I am a newbie here, and I don't know how to better discuss here - in comments or by making answers to own questions.

Comment: lists are monadic. also Monads in code essentially compose code as a stream. The way I see it,  A Monad and a Stream is the same concept; both summarized as "collections whose values are extracted by passing a callback". You don't simply get 5th item from a Stream; many apis allow it but it's frowned upon because your process will block on the stream until it gets the response from the stream. Instead you ask it to get the fifth item and do something with the result once it's available, or handle if it's not via callback/promise/future. So how are monads and streams different?

Comment: note, streams suffer from the same confusion of putting things back into them as monads; once you take a string out of a stringstream, you can't just cons it back into the stream; you need to push(>>=) it in(<< in c++) and append it from within the Stream, as within a StringStream monad lies a simple string that you can append to. Monads seem to be StrictStreams in that they force all transformations within the monad to agree with the Monad; you can't do IO inside a StringStream monad without unsafePerformIO

Comment: A bit late to this party, but for posterity's sake: streams are comonadic, which is the opposite ('dual') notion to monadic.